# How can I speed up this regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am using Rails 3.2.11 on Ruby 1.9.2p320.

I have created a `summarized()` method to show where certain keywords appear in a series of 1,000 to 15,000 word documents that are stored as text strings. Each document can contain each keyword anywhere from 0 to 100 times.

I have:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130404000559) do
  create_table "references", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "source_text"
  end
end
```

When I call `@reference.source_text.summarize(keywords)`, the following method is phenomenally slow, *even when there is just one `keyword` in `keywords`*:

```
class String
  def summarized(keywords)
    safe_text = Array.new
    result = String.new
    keywords.each do |keyword|
      safe_text << self.strip_tags.gsub(/\n|\r/, " ").gsub("  ", " ").scan(/\w*.{0,250}#{keyword}.{0,250}\w*/im)
    end    
    return safe_text.flatten.uniq
  end    
end
```

How can I speed it up?

**Update**: I'm now looking at the possibility that `strip_tags` [may be at least one of the culprits](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2012/01/08/dont-use-strip_tags/).

Comment: How many keywords are there? You are iterating the string at least 3 times for each keyword. Is it slow with 1 keyword already?

Comment: Potentially it could be up to five keywords, but realistically it will usually it's just one keyword, and it's slow even with just one keyword.

Comment: You only want their position?

Comment: No I need show text snippets. So if the word "foo" appears in the middle of @reference.source_text, I show about 503 characters, consisting of the roughly 250 chars just before "foo", then "foo", then the roughly 250 chars that follow.

Comment: @steven_noble what behavior do you expect if your keyword appears twice in a short time? Atm, your regexp would skip the second one.

Comment: It actually picks up every instance at the present. I get a list of text snippets, each surrounding one instance of the keyword. It behaves correctly, but it takes forever!

Comment: I can't see how it could work as of now. If your keyword is say... *keyword* and you have *keyword some random works keyword*. The second keyword will appear simply as a word in the snippet of the first keyword. Which as I'm writing this doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: I can only tell you what I'm seeing, which is output that meets my needs, but after a wait that's far too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's begin by why it is slow. Your regex starts like that:

```
/\w*.{0,250}
```

Now let's start with the worse case (and quite a frequent one in your case). You have like 1000 characters without your keyword. Your regex will first the first word, then check 250 chracters later if your keyword is here. Nope. It will go backward to the 249th. Still nope. 250 tries later, will begin doing the same with the `\w*` part. You're lucky, words are pretty short. **And it will do the same for the next (at least) 749 characters.** So, in the worse case, you go through your string like 250 times. [Laziness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) would fix the problem, however, I assume it's not the behavior you want (this `.{0,250}` is to deal with the beginning of the string, isn't it?).

Now, a cool regex tool is lookarounds. You can go ahead or back in your string to make some additional checks. While it won't be part of the captured strings, you can use capturing groups in them.
The drawback? You can't have arbitrary size loobehind (damn, just what you needed). So it wouldn't quite work cause you couldn't make sure you have a whole word at the beginning  but also you wouldn't be able to match a keyword in the 250 first characters of the string.

So, here's a strange solution:
- Add 250 characters at the beginning of your string (whitespaces?..) to make sure we can catch words at the beginning.
- Use this regex (you can take into account what m_x said and use it only once for all the keywords):

```
/#{keyword}(?<=(.{250}))(.{0,250}\w*)/im
```

Then manipulate quite a bit the result (recombine the string by adding the captured groups, remove the eventual characters that were part of the 250 ones added, maybe remove the first word to make sure it's whole...) and it should be quite faster.

**Edit (comment about the regex):**

You could be wondering why the `(?<=(.{250}))` is placed AFTER the keyword. Well, it's just so the capturing is made after you matched a keyword. It also means the keyword will also be part of the capturing group, and the capturing group will only capture 250-keyword.length characters before the keyword(well it's not much of a problem, you can create your regex dynamically depending on the length of your keyword, and anyway, it's not much of a problem I guess). You could also place the lookbehind after the first character of the keyword but that'd be a pain... Well I'll stop my monologue here.

Comment: Awesome. It's 1.37am here AEST so I'm going to hit the sack but this is the very first thing I'm trying in the morning and I'll be sure to report back pronto.

Comment: Btw, forgot some comment about the regex, updating.

Comment: Even without formal performance testing I can see that your version is at last 10x faster than the version it replaces, so thanks!

Comment: far better than my answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

How about this ? you would only scan the string once.

```
/\w*.{0,250}#{keywords.join('|')}.{0,250}\w*/im
```

As a side note, this kind of app would likely benefit from an indexed search engine like [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/).

Comment: Thanks! :-) So I take it this means multiple keywords scan as quickly as one keyword, but doesn't speed up the scan when I already have just one keyword? I'm using pg_search with a search index, but it returns the entire string, not a snippet.

Comment: ...which is why I've created the summarize() method -- to convert the text string into a snippet. :-)

Comment: it won't speed things up if you have only one keyword. The reason it speeds things up when you have multiple keywords is that with your solution you create a new regex and scan the entire, extremely long string for each keyword. I don't understand what you say about `pg_search`

Comment: Cheers. Just saying (a) I am using an indexed search engine, pg_search, though it's possible it's different to Sunspot in ways I don't appreciate, and (b) the search engine just says which 15,000 word docs contain my search terms, but it doesn't pull these 500-characters snippets for me, hence the summarize()method.

Comment: mmm... maybe you should extract those snippets from the start, and index them directly. A background job would do it. Apart from that, i'm afraid this problem exceeds my knowledge

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I do currently call summarize() from within a delayed_job at present, right after I use pg_search to find the search results.

Comment: I have added you regex though so I don't slow myself further when using multiple keywords, so thanks.